# How do I get to know which files in my installer were replaced with a merge module?

Tags: windows-installer, software-packaging, merge-module

I had a non msi installer that I repackaged using Flexera Repackager.

It put a merge module in my msi package that was not necessary (it put a lot of files in the package that I do not need and the application doesn't use this mm....). So I got out the mm from the package but I'm curious which file in the package induced the importing of the mm. (I did not find any differences between the original and the msi installed app.)

So how can I find out which file was it?

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I used the repackager but here are a few thoughts:

1) I think there's a setting to turn substitution on or off.
2) I believe it generates a log when it creates the .inc.irp.ism files.
3) After you build the MSI, you could always edit it in ORCA (or the IS direct editor) and see which entries in the file tables are modularized with GUID suffixes.  Then you could look at the ModuleSignature table to see what those module identities are.  You could also use the redistributables view to see which modules are included and what their file contents are.